# Consuming API's using AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, api

I am a newcomer to AWS with very little cloud experience. The project I have is to call and consume a API from NOAA, and then save parse the returned XML document to a database. I have a ASP.NET console app that is able to do this pretty easily and successfully. However, I need to do the same thing, but in the cloud on a serverless architecture. Here are the steps I am wanting it to take:

1. Lambda calls the API at NOAA everyday at midnight
2. the API returns an XML doc with results
3. Parse the data and save the data to a cloud PostgreSQL database

It sounds simple, but I am having one heck of a time figuring out how to do this. I have a DB requisitioned from AWS, as that is where data is currently going through my console app. Does anyone have any advice or a resource I could look at for advice? Also, I would prefer to keep this in .NET, but realize that I may need to move it to Python.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: Depending on how professional you want this to be, there may be a lot of things you need to learn. I'd start with a couple of basic [serverless app development on AWS](https://www.google.com/search?q=serverless+app+development+on+aws) or [serverless cron on AWS](https://www.serverless.com/blog/cron-jobs-on-aws) resources. You'll ultimately create an [Amazon EventBridge rule that runs on a schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html) to run your Lambda function periodically. Your Lambda function can be written in C# .Net Core.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple and you can test your code with below simple python boto3 lambda code.

- Create new lambda function with admin access (temporary set Admin role and then you can set required role)
- Add the following code

https://github.com/mmakadiya/public_files/blob/main/lambda_call_get_rest_api.py

```
import json
import urllib3


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    r = http.request('GET', 'http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json')
    print(r.data)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

The above code will run the REST API to fetch the data.  This is just a sample program and it will help you to go further.

MAKE SURE that Lambda function max run time is `15 minutes and it can not be run >15 min so think accordingly.